# Equations with operations from multiple rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

My questions is about equations that combine operations from different rings/fields.  For example, an equation using bitwise XOR and modular addition.

e.g. a = (b xor c) + d mod 2^n, where n is some positive integer and a,b,c,d are binary strings of length n

Or in other words, there is a clear mapping between the elements of the ring Z mod 2^n and the field GF(2^n), and equations combining them seem to be well-defined.  But I have never seen any area of math that address these sorts of equations.

Is there any area of algebra that addresses such relationships between different rings/fields (maybe something like a generalized chinese remainder theorem)?

Thanks